# Meteor on iPad 'Could not connect to the server sockjs' error

Tags: meteor

i have this meteor app deployed on iPad
when my meteor app is starting i have this error

> Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server sockjs

this error doesn't occur when i am debugging the same application on my browser

it is quite wired because i never had it before and plus i am not connecting to any meteor server but just connecting to a regular websocket (later).

and i use

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  Meteor.disconnect();
}
```

what should i change?

Comment: Where did you put that function? As the docs says, you should put that call only client side, not serverside.

Comment: it is on the client because i have no server at all

Comment: if you use Meteor.disconnect() from the client side, you won't be able to handle any DDP (or websocket) connection through the lifecycle of your app.